# Invalid column count on Line 1 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm running the following query via PHP:

```
INSERT INTO Plans 
( Plan
, Client_ID
, Last_Name
, First_Name
, Notes
, DDD_Case
, Plan_Status
, UID
, Initial_Plan1
, Program
, Plan_Approval_Date
, Approval_Date
, PEA_Update
, Plan_End_Date) VALUES 
( '1'
, '1515'
, 'Father'
, 'NotReal'
, ''
, '3333'
, 'Active'
, '3333_1'
, '0'
, 'CCP-Short'
, '09/17/2020'
, '09/17/2020'
, '11/19/2020'
, '')
```

I'm getting this error, though:

```
 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

It then fails to insert the record into the Plans table.  Can someone give me a hand here?  It looks like I'm using the correct number of values and fields, but it won't go in.

This is the pastebin to the table schema (create table Plans) because someone in the comments asked for it:

https://pastebin.com/zJep8jHn

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In the question you say php, but the title says PhpMyAdmin. Which one is the source of the error? Or both perhaps?

Comment: the count match, can you provide a [mre] with also the table as CREATE TABLE

Comment: Please provide table schema and ensure that no data has an unescaped apostrophe.

Comment: @El_Vanja It's a phpmyadmin error (or MySQL error).  I get the error when I run the query directly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The create table command for the table is too long to paste here directly.  Here's the pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/zJep8jHn

Comment: I checked it for unescaped apostrophes.  That shouldn't be an issue, though, because the code I'm working with sanitizes the data with mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Don't sanitize data that way. Use prepared and bound queries instead.

Comment: That said, this table (as described on pastebin) is highly symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: And in any case, this query is not generating that error, which often suggests that there is a forgotten TRIGGER in play in the background.

Comment: (And if you're going to store dates that way, probably best not to bother with an RDBMS)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224855/discussion-between-brian-hartman-and-strawberry).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with the triggers.  What happened is that I added columns to the table, but the developer who added the triggers didn't realize it, and I didn't realize there were triggers that depended on the columns, so when I added the columns, the triggers broke, making the query break.

Comment: Yes, you did. :)  Thanks! :)